# How to promote a workflow build

Tags: jenkins-workflow

Is there a way to promote a build when using Jenkins Workflow project? 
Snippet generator does not yet show promote as a generic build step or separate step?

Documentation says "Workflow is intended to supersede in part or in whole (Parameterized Trigger, Copy Artifact, Join, Promoted Builds, Build Pipeline, EnvInject, etc.)"

I want to distinguish good builds from bad builds (e.g. add a gold star based on results of tests). Is it possible to use "[Promoted Build plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin)" from workflow script? Alternatively is there a equivalent way to achieve similar goal of marking good builds from workflow script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the Promoted Builds plugin with Workflow.

You can use

```
currentBuild.description = 'Failed!'
```

There is not currently a plugin allowing you to add badges to Workflow builds, but I think it would be simple to write.

Answer (score 1):

From [DZone ref card](https://dzone.com/refcardz/continuous-delivery-with-jenkins-workflow) I understand you could also use

```
input 'Are you sure?'
```

or

```
input message: 'Are you sure?', ok: 'Deploy', submitter: 'qa-team'
```

in your script in order to add a manual approval task